# S3 bucket delete object access denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need help with s3 bucket using ,
my Bucket policy for actions is -->

```
  "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ]
```

getting the objects working fine
putting objects working fine

but when i try to delete object or multiple objects with
s3.deleteObject / s3.deleteObjects i get

```
  Code: 'Access Denied',
      Message: 'Access Denied'
```

as a response

any one has any idea how can i fix that ???

i tried to make the action "s3:*: to include all actions but i still get the same result

i tried to make a new bucket and still get the same results

Comment: Show the actual policy, to include the actions and their associated resource ARNs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Delete permission on the content of the bucket as well (`/*`):

```
{
    "Action": ["s3:DeleteObject"], 
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"], 
    "Effect": "Allow"
},
```

Comment: This is my bucket policy, still not working 


{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::almasa-project-bucket/*"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: s3:*, also add this to the resource: "arn:aws:s3:::almasa-project-bucket"

Comment: `"Principal": ""` is not a valid principal.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found that AWS added AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantine to the User since the keys were exposed by fault